# C++ Blackjack code only going to first if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to code a blackjack game and everything is going smoothly so far but for this bit. No matter what I input into `hitStand` it always goes to the first if statement and "hits". I would like for if "h" is inputted it "Hits" and if "s" is inputted it "Stands" and, if there is an invalid input, it will tell the user to try again.

I'm still fairly new to C++, so some help would be appreciated.

```
while (repeat == 0)
            {
                char hitStand;
                cout << "Would you like to HIT or STAND [H/S]";
                cin >> hitStand;
                if (hitStand = "H" || "h")
                {
                    PcardNew = rand() % 13 + 1;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Your new card is: " << PcardNew << endl;
                    if (PcardNew > 10)
                    {
                        PcardNew = 10;
                    }
                    playerTotal = playerTotal + PcardNew; 
                    cout << "Your new total is: " << playerTotal << endl;
                }
                else if (hitStand = "S" || "s")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Please enter a valid imput [H/S]" << endl;
                }
            }
```

Comment: = and == are not the same operator. Your if statement is assigning a value to hitStand ...

Comment: `hiStand = "H" || "h"` isn't the same as `hitStand == "H" || hitStand =="h"`.

Comment: `"H"` and `"h"` are pointers to string literals. If you want to compare the character codes, you should write `'H'` and `'h'` instead.

Comment: if I use the == operator it gives me an error saying "operand types are incompatible ("char" and "constchar")

Comment: Just as an additional explanation: `hitStand == 'H' || 'h'` is equivalent to `hitStand == 'H' || 'h' != 0`, because in C, an expression is true if it is non-zero. That is obviously not what you want, because the right side of the `||` will always be true, which means that the entire condition will always be true. That is why you must write `hitStand == 'H' || hitStand == 'h'` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) three errors in the single `if (hitStand = "H" || "h")` line!

First, the `=` operator is an assignment, not a comparison; to test for the equality of two operands, you need the `==` operator.

Second, the `"H"` and `"h"` constants are *string literals* - that is, multi-character, null-terminated strings of characters. Use single quotes for single characters (thus, `'H'` and `'h'`).

Third, you can't compare one object with two others like that with a logical or (`||`) operator. You need to make two *separate* comparisons and then **or** the results of each:

So, use this:

```c
if (hitStand == 'H' || hitStand == 'h')
{
   //...
```

And similarly for your second test:

```c
else if (hitStand == 'S' || hitStand == 's')
{
    //...
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone, so much for the help, these were all very very helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

That is because your condition in if statement is always true. Since "h" is in or (||).

Instead use:

```c
if (hitStand == 'H' || hitStand == 'h')
```

and

```c
else if (hitStand == 'S' || hitStand =='s')
```

Comment: I have made the edits, now using a single quote since it is char.